# iOS Keyboard doesn't hide fully and view is stuck using RxKeyboard observer

Tags: ios, swift, reactive

Sometimes keyboard do not dismiss fully and the view is stuck. Why it happens?

[image]

In code I perform updates the following way:

1. In `viewDidLoad` I simply add observer using RxKeyboard:

   ```
    RxKeyboard.instance.visibleHeight.drive(onNext: { height in
        myView.updateOffset(with: height)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
   ```
2. In `myView` there is a method for it:

   ```
    func updateOffset(with offset: CGFloat) {
        containerView.snp.updateConstraints { maker in
            // update offset here using SnapKit
        }
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
   ```

What do I miss that it sometimes stuck and does not work?